# How to place an element relative to two elements by calculating top and left position dynamically using react or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

I have an `svg`, content-box `div` and popup dialog `div` elements. I want to place `svg` (which is an arrow and is inside a `div`) such that the `svg` top is in the right center of the content-box and left is in the center of popup dialog box.

Image is as shown below.
[image]

I want to find the top and left position for `svg` element and rotation such that it is not misaligned when resolution change.

i have tried something like below, where i get the content-box top and left positions and popup dialog...i want to also calculate the lenght for svg which later is used to set the width and height of svg..

the below calculations are not proper...the svg is shown in different place based on resolution. i want it to remain the same no matter what the resolution is.

```
positioning = () => {
    const alignment = 'right';
    const popup_dialog_element = document.querySelector("selector to get the popup dialog);
    const context_box_element = document.querySelector("some selector");
    const popup_dialog_rect = popup_dialog_element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const content_box_rect = content_box_element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const start_position = this.get_position(content_box_rect, alignment);
    const end_position = this.get_position(popup_dialog_rect);
    const length = Math.hypot(end_position.x-start_position.x, end_position.y-start_position.y);
    const center_x = (start_position.x + end_position.x) / 2;
    const center_y = (start_position.y + end_position.y) / 2;
    const rotation = this.get_angle_of_rotation(center_x, center_y, end_position.x, end_position.y);
    svg_element.style.transform = `rotate(${rotation})`;
    svg_element.style.top = start_position.y + 'px';
    svg_element.style.left = end_position.x + 'px';
    svg_element.style.width = length + 'px';
    svg_element.style.height = length + 'px';
}

get_angle_of_rotation = (cx,cy,x,y) => {
    const dy = y - center_y;
    const dx = x - center_x;
    let theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    theta *= 180 / Math.PI;
    if (theta < 0) theta = 360 + theta;
    return theta + 'deg';
}

get_position = (rect, alignment) => {
    switch(alignment) {
        case 'left':
            return {x: rect.left, y: rect.top + (rect.height / 2)};
        case 'top':
            return {x: rect.left + (rect.width / 2) , y: rect.top};
        case 'bottom':
            return {x: rect.left + (rect.width / 2), y: rect.bottom};
        case 'right':
            return {x: rect.right, y: rect.top + (rect.height / 2)};
        default:
            return {x: rect.left + (rect.width / 2), y: rect.top + (rect.height / 2)};
    }
}
```

Could someone help me fix this. i want the svg element to be aligned properly next to the content_box center and the arrow should end at the center of the popup dialog. or let me know how to position the div in between as shown in picture. thanks.

Comment: A codepen or forkable code would be really helpful. Also are you calling these methods on `resize`?

Comment: i am calling these in componentdidupdate hook...